# UIButtons not showing up in UIScrollView

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiscrollview, uibutton

I'm trying to get an email address, create a button from it, and then add that button to UIScrollView.

The issues is that the buttons aren't visible in UIScrollView. The emails are being added to the list, and the buttons are being created but aren't visible.

Code:

```
import UIKit

let BUTTON_SPACING = 10
let BUTTON_HEIGHT = 40

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var mailField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!

var fileUrl = NSURL()
var emails = [String]()

var mailButtArr: [UIButton] = []
var deletButtArr: [UIButton] = []

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    let documentsURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]
    print(documentsURL)
    fileUrl = documentsURL.appendingPathComponent("emails.plist") as NSURL

    let fileManager = FileManager.default
    if(!fileManager.fileExists(atPath: fileUrl.path!))
    {
        print("email.plist is not found with filemanager")
        NSKeyedArchiver.archiveRootObject(emails, toFile: fileUrl.path!)
    }
    else
    {
        emails = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(withFile: fileUrl.path!) as! [String]
        print(emails.count, " emails found ")
        for s in emails
        {
            print(s)
            addNewButton(title: s)
        }
    }
    mailField.text = "xyz@mail.com"
}

@IBAction func AddEmail(sender: AnyObject)
{
    mailField.resignFirstResponder()

    let email: String = mailField.text!

    emails.append(email)
    mailField.text = "xyz@mail.com"

    NSKeyedArchiver.archiveRootObject(emails, toFile: fileUrl.path!)
    print("saved")

    addNewButton(title: email)
}

@objc func buttonTouched(sender: UIButton)
{
    let urlString: String = sender.titleLabel!.text!
    let url: NSURL = NSURL(string: urlString)!
    UIApplication.shared.openURL(url as URL)
}

func addNewButton(title: String)
{
    let butt: UIButton = UIButton()
    butt.setTitle(title, for: .normal)

    butt.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
    butt.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    butt.layer.borderWidth = 0.5
    butt.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0

    butt.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.buttonTouched(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    mailButtArr.append(butt)
    mailButtArr = mailButtArr.sorted {$0.titleLabel!.text! < $1.titleLabel!.text!}

    let newHeight: Float = Float((mailButtArr.count) * (BUTTON_HEIGHT + BUTTON_SPACING)) + Float(BUTTON_SPACING)
    let contentSize: CGSize = CGSize(width: scrollView.frame.size.width, height: CGFloat(newHeight))

    scrollView.contentSize = contentSize

    refreshList()
}

func refreshList()
{
    let subviews = scrollView.subviews as [UIView]
    for v in subviews
    {
        if let button = v as? UIButton
        {
            button.removeFromSuperview()
        }
    }
    deletButtArr.removeAll()

    var buttonOffset: CGFloat = CGFloat(BUTTON_SPACING)

    for button: UIButton in mailButtArr
    {
        var buttonFrame: CGRect = button.frame
        buttonFrame.origin.x = CGFloat(BUTTON_SPACING)
        buttonFrame.origin.y = buttonOffset

        buttonFrame.size.width = 200
        buttonFrame.size.height = CGFloat(BUTTON_HEIGHT)
        print("X:", BUTTON_SPACING, " Y:", buttonOffset, " W: ", buttonFrame.size.width, " H: ", BUTTON_HEIGHT)
        scrollView.addSubview(button)

       /* let delButt: UIButton = UIButton(type: .detailDisclosure)
        deletButtArr.append(delButt)
        buttonFrame = delButt.frame
        buttonFrame.origin.x = 340
        buttonFrame.origin.y = buttonOffset + 10
        delButt.frame = buttonFrame

        scrollView.addSubview(delButt)*/

        buttonOffset += CGFloat(BUTTON_HEIGHT + BUTTON_SPACING)
    }
}
```

}

Most of this code is copied from an in-class demonstration that I'm trying to modify for the assignment.

Comment: One way you can debug is use view debugging in XCode. If you turn on View hierarchy you should be able to see where the buttons are. If you cannot find them then it means they were not added to the scroll view properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, based on this code I see a couple of issues from the start.

Your `addNewButton` function creates a button but does not set a frame or constraint, and it only adds that button to an array.

First I was thinking what the other answer said, that you are not adding the button to the view, but then I saw that you do add the button to the view on the `refreshList` function.

And inside that function you actually create a button frame, but you never assign that frame to the button before adding to the view.

So first test in you case is right before `scrollView.addSubview(button)` add:
`button.frame = buttonFrame` and see if that works

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the new button as a subview in your ViewController's view class
so that it will appear on the UI.

```
func addNewButton(title: String)
{
  let butt: UIButton = UIButton()
..
..
  self.view.addSubview(butt)
}
```